# SSH through a tunnel or directly depending on the network I'm conncted to

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel, gateway

Is it possible to "automatically" configure ssh to use a gateway to connect to a remote machine based on the client's IP address or something in the likes?

Suppose I'm at my `laptop`, which I can plug (via a wired connection) into the university network and have direct access to the `cluster.uni.edu`, but if I'm at home, I must hop through the `gateway.uni.edu`. So, to connect to the cluster from home, I can have my `~/.ssh/config` like this:

```
Host cluster
    Host cluster.uni.edu
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p gateway.uni.edu
```

So I can just `ssh cluster` and access it transparently hopping though the gateway. The downside is that if I'm plugged to the university network, I don't need to go through the gateway, so to avoid it I would have to do something like `ssh cluster.uni.edu`.

Is it possible to set up this so ssh doesn't hop though the gateway it it's not needed? The criterion would be something like: *If eth0 is connected and the IP is xxx.yyy.zzz.www, connect directly, otherwise use the gateway*.

I think this might be a lot to ask from the configuration file and standard ssh options alone, but I would really like to avoid wrapper scripts. (Side note: I used LocalFowrard to do this kind of thing before I learned about `ssh -W` because I didn't like the idea of using `netcat` as `ProxyCommand`)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't suppose just having a second `Host cluster1` entry without the proxy would be enough?  So `ssh cluster` when external, and `ssh cluster1` when internal?

Comment: you can use your own script for proxycommand to decide whether to connect via a proxy or shortcut the connection directly to the final target.

Comment: @Paul: yes, I could do that, but I was curious about the possibilities of ssh_config

Comment: @sparkie: Another possibility that occurred to me, that's why I mentioned I'm trying to avoid wrapper scripts.

Comment: Also, with tab completion working, it doesn't really hurt to type `ssh clus<tab>.<tab>`, so the `Host` section just for an alias is not needed.

Having the same hostname to automagically decide whether to use a proxy or not would be useful for example in scripts (Backup, job submission etc.), which would not need themselves to check to which network I'm connected.

Comment: Ah right, no I don't think you can get this done with ssh alone, it would need some scripting.  Though you could probably put the test into the `ProxyCommand` command line, to avoid an external script.

Comment: Try [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/1259671/432690). Note the examples there use `-J`, but in your case it's enough to use `cluster.uni.edu` and `cluster` in this exact order. The command will be like `sshmt cluster.uni.edu +3 cluster +7`. It should work, if only `ssh cluster.uni.edu` fails with exit status `255` in circumstances where you need to use `ssh cluster` instead.