# Windows CMD "or" Symbol ("||") Only Works Sometimes

Tags: linux, ssh, cmd.exe

I have written a batch script on my windows ten laptop (I am used to bash scripting, so this might be a simple cmd scripting answer) that sshs into my Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 at home no matter where I am, and it looks like this:

```
@echo off
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=3 root@192.168.1.41 2>NUL || ssh root@myhomeip
pause
```

Now that usually works, but when I'm actually at home, and it connects using the first `ssh -o ConnectTimeout=3 root@192.168.1.41 2>NUL` (connect timeout set so it doesn't try too long to connect to private ip address if I'm not at home, wasn't working with netbios name some time ago so I changed it to this. Errors redirected so it doesn't give me some useless error message before trying public ip address), it connects and gives me a session, but when I exit, every once in a while it will immediately log me back in with the second command, despite the "or" symbol in place (||). This would be fine to just use the public address everytime, except that when I'm actually on my home network, connecting with the public ip is ***slightly*** slower than with the private ip, which is why I made this script in the first place. I believe this is happening because ssh occasionally exits with an error status for some reason, and this triggers the second command to be executed even though I already logged in and out of my server. I am wondering why that might be and how to fix it.

---

This is my first question, so please forgive any errors or other inconveniences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe this is happening because `ssh` occasionally exits with an error status for some reason

An interactive shell terminated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, `exit` or `logout` exits with the exit status of the last command executed in the shell. In your case the shell is remote and if there is no problem with the local `ssh` itself then `ssh` will repeat the remote exit status locally. The reason you're talking about is the last command in the shell; it apparently failed and its non-zero exit status propagated to the local side.

Possible solutions:

- Always `exit 0` or `logout 0` by hand (inconvenient).
- Use `trap … EXIT` in the remote shell and execute `exit 0` in the trap (cumbersome).
- Put `exit 0` as the last command in `.bash_logout` or equivalent script. This is specific to the shell you're using on the remote side, some shells don't provide this functionality. The code in the script may be conditional (check if the parent process is `sshd`; or check if the `SSH_CONNECTION` variable is in the environment).
- Instead of `ssh -o ConnectTimeout=3 root@192.168.1.41` use:

  ```
  ssh -t -o ConnectTimeout=3 root@192.168.1.41 '"$SHELL"; exit 0'
  ```

  Disadvantages:

  - there are two nested shells on the remote side;
  - your remote shell may modify its behavior when invoked from `sshd`; in this case the outer shell will do this, but the inner shell won't, this may cause the whole setup behave not exactly as you wish.
- Check the actual exit status of `ssh` (locally); it will be `255` if an error occurs. You need to replace `||` with some logic that tells apart `255` from any other exit status. I cannot reliably write this for you because I don't know `cmd.exe` good enough. I *guess* it will be like `if ERRORLEVEL 255 ssh …`.

  Note if the remote shell returns `255` then it will make your local code think `ssh` failed. There is no easy way to avoid this. Nevertheless **testing against `255` is the solution I would choose if I were you**. I actually do this in my [SSH wrapper that tries several connection parameters](https://superuser.com/a/1259671/432690).

Comment: Oooooh, I knew ssh exits with status of the remote command when specifying one on the local side, but I didn't know that it also did that for interactive sessions. I don't know cmd very well either, so I could look into how to do that later. For now, though, could I just alias `exit` to `exit 0` in `sshrc`? Or just check for $SSH_CONNECTION in bashrc  then do that?