# Why does "last" command return logins from "192.168.1.1"?

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-20.04

Every time I look at the login history on my Ubuntu server (20.04.3), I see a few entries from my router's ip "192.168.1.1". I myself log in remotely via ssh, but my sessions don't coincide with these. If I use the -d option, it confirms it is my router by substituting these entries with my router my router name.local. Each session log is only a couple seconds at the most, so I can't see what it is doing while it's logged in, and I don't think it is a person. Why is that showing up, or if my router actually has something to do with it, then what?

Comment: I would run tcpdump and ask for traffic from your router and see what it's doing. `last` should at least tell you the user involved.

Comment: I know the user it logged in as is root, same as me. forgot to mention that. I don't know tcpdump very well, and I don't know if I could interpret the output, but I'll look into it. Funny story, one time I happened to be logged in and using the machine and used `w` and it showed there was 2 users logged in, then it only listed me! I then did `watch last` and revealed it was my router still logged on, so I did all I could to see what it was doing and tried to log it off, but to no avail, so I just restarted it.

Comment: @Bib could you put your comment into a more detailed answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this one out on my own. If you'll look at my other question regarding this server ([Windows CMD "or" Symbol ("||") Only Works Sometimes](https://superuser.com/questions/1689010/windows-cmd-or-symbol-only-works-sometimes/1689030#1689030)) the problem there is the cause of this one too. You see, every time SSH exited with 255, it caused the script to log me in again via my public ip which my router forwards to the server thus logging me in again which is annoying, but every time that happened I just harrumphed and immediately logged out again (which explains why the session is logged as usually under a minute) without ever checking what was going on. Now from that question being answered it is clear that it is because of the last command being run giving the error status and causing my local computer to log in again, so I tried reproducing the problem and checking things out when logging in from the local subnet but through the public ip. Usually when logging in remotely it will actually show the public ip of the client as the source of the user it is logged in as, but when using the same command from the local network and running `w`, I can see that it thinks it is coming from the router because it is forwarding the connection from my laptop to the server even though they are both on the same network

[image: screenshot]